# Using Imagemagick, add watermark outside the image eg. using padding, in bulk?

Tags: imagemagick, padding, watermark

I am trying to add a watermark outside the image, creating firstly a padding place.

- a) How can I do that? My imagemagick command have problem. Do not
  cover all my image files eg. "DSC_5568 - DSC_5588_fused.jpg" did not add padding.
- b) I can combine the two separate commands?
- c) I want to do that in bulk

My imagemagick commands:

```
for pic in DSC*.*; do convert -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+100 $pic ${pic//.*}-padded.jpg; done

for pic in DSC*padded.*;  do composite -dissolve 100% -gravity SouthEast watermark.png $pic ${pic//.*}-marked.jpg; done
```

example filenames:

> "DSC_5568.JPG, DSC_5568 - DSC_5588_fused.jpg.... etc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really should provide sample input and expected output images, but I think you want this:

```
convert INPUT.JPG -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+100 -gravity southeast watermark.png -compose dissolve -composite RESULT.JPG
```

You may need to add this `-define`:

```
... watermark.png -define compose:args=100 -compose dissolve -composite ...
```

---

If that works, I would make a **COPY** of all your files **in a spare directory** and do the whole lot in parallel with **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel 'convert {} -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+100 -gravity southeast watermark.png -compose dissolve -composite {.}-marked.jpg' ::: *.jpg
```

---

Or, if you prefer a simple bash `for` loop:

```
for f in DSC* ; do
   convert "$f" -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+100 -gravity southeast watermark.png -compose dissolve -composite "${f//.*}-marked.jpg"
done
```

Comment: If it doesn't work, please say what went wrong and click `edit` under your original question and add input and expected output images. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how to process all my image files, using "" on the specified filenames.

```
for pic in DSC*.*; do convert -background black -extent 0%x0%+0+100 "$pic" "${pic//.*}-padded.jpg"; done

for pic in DSC*-padded.*;  do composite -dissolve 100% -gravity SouthEast watermark.png "$pic" "${pic//.*}-marked.jpg"; done
```